# DefinePlugin not running immediately after html-loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader

I’m trying to use `DefinePlugin` with `html-loader`. I’m using interpolation in `html-loader`, and trying to use values from `DefinePlugin` in the interpolated expressions.

This works when I load into `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, or when `html-loader` is the only loader used for the html file, but if I load from `html-loader` into `extract-loader`, `DefinePlugin` doesn’t appear to do its replacement before `extract-loader` tries to process the file data.

Example:

```
src/index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>${ TITLE }</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
webpack.config.js:

const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: [
    "./src/index.html"
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              interpolate: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      TITLE: JSON.stringify('My page title')
    }),
  ]
};
```

This works as expected, and when observing the output `main.js`, the interpolated part of the HTML has been replaced with the `My page title` value of `TITLE`.

Of course, I want to extract this HTML to a separate file using `extract-loader` and `file-loader`. Taking this one step at a time, I first add `extract-loader` to process the output from `html-loader`, as follows:

```
...
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
+++       "extract-loader",
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              interpolate: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
...
```

This results in a build failure:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.html
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/extract-loader/lib/extractLoader.js):
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) ReferenceError: TITLE is not defined
```

My expectation is that since files are processed by loaders sequentially, `TITLE` should have already been replaced by the time `extractLoader.js` is ready to touch it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have this same issue.

Comment: Subscribe to https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/241